# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /register/ User has no schoolprofile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

hello am trying to create a school profile when a user( schooluser) registers,the profile is created but giving the error RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /register/User has no schoolprofile.and the strange thing is that in the admin the model fields when you try to edit any field of the created school profile they are empty.
help.

### models.py

```python
class SchoolProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='schoolprofile')
    schoolname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    logo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='logos')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

### forms.py

```python
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import SchoolProfile



class SchoolRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
   

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

  
class SchoolProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SchoolProfile
        fields = ['schoolname', 'code', 'region']
```

### views.py

```python
from .forms import SchoolRegisterForm,SchoolProfileForm



def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SchoolRegisterForm(request.POST)
        s_profile_form = SchoolProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and s_profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            request.user.refresh_from_db()  
            s_profile_form = SchoolProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.schoolprofile)
            s_profile_form.full_clean()
            s_profile_form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in!')
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = SchoolRegisterForm()
        s_profile_form = SchoolProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form,'s_profile_form':s_profile_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `request.user.schoolprofile`, but your user (right now) has not per se a *related* `SchoolProfile` object, hence the error. Furthermore creating a user will not (automatically) log in that user. You can alter the `.user` field in the instance wrapped in the `s_profile_form`:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SchoolRegisterForm(request.POST)
        s_profile_form = SchoolProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and s_profile_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            s_profile_form.instance.user = user
            s_profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in!')
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = SchoolRegisterForm()
        s_profile_form = SchoolProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form,'s_profile_form':s_profile_form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: The note you provided I can't tell big difference can you help with some examples please

Comment: i have tried your solution am getting this error IntegrityError at /register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_schoolprofile.user_id

Comment: @cipher: that is because you are registering a profile to a user that already exists. You should not specify `instance=...` in the `SchoolRegisterForm`, since then you are creating a new `SchoolProfile` for that user.

Comment: @cipher: did you by any chance use signals to create a `SchoolProfile`?

Comment: Yes I have used signals

Comment: @cipher: please do not use signals. Only in very specific cases these are necessary. In general these are more an *anti-pattern*: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ especially since the records that are produced are not (automatically) reflected in forms, and many ORM calls circumvent these.